# Can a quick deploy job be used on a list?

Tags: list, content-deployment

We are currently developing a FAQ list, that will be used to fill a FAQ page. So the content of the page will be a query to the FAQ list and all the FAQs will be displayed on the spot. The question is, if it is possible to Quick Deploy a list or a list item?

Thanks for the info,

Comment: Yes. It is possible to implement quick deploy on list items..

Answer (score 1):

Using the web browser and SP2007 I think it's only pages that can be quick deployed.

Do you really need a quick deploy job to do this?  Are your FAQs so rapidly changing that they need to be deployed every 15mins?

If so, you could create a normal content deployment job in Central Admin and schedule it to run every 15 mins......

Comment: Use the Incremental Deploy(Run Now) from central Admin  option once changing the list

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

So quick deploy is standard only possible on page level. This means that if an update is done in the Reusable content list or in the image library, that the page on which the item is used must be (quickly) deployed. So this procedure needs to happen on all pages where the list item is used? 
It would be more practical if the list item could be deployed to all pages where it used. This way you only need to deploy it once.

But maybe we can use the Incremental Deploy (Run now), as commented by Thomson. But this means that the entire site will be deployed, looking for changes on the entire site?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: In Incrementatal Deploy the entire site wont be going only the changes will be going